# GnuPlot error: "Format must have 1-7 conversions of type double"

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I have no idea what cause the following error:

> Format must have 1-7 conversions of type double.

My input file is formated correctly. I use the following command:

> plot "input.txt" using 1:2 "title"

All on the image below:
[image: screen]

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your text file? Your screenshot is cutting off the rest of the text

Comment: Corrected the screenshot. P.S. I got the same error with all files that have doubles, it works fine for integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
plot "input.txt" using 1:2 title "title"
```

If you have a string directly following the `using` statement, then this is interpreted as a format specifier. From the docs:

```
plot 'file' using <entry> {:<entry> {:<entry> ...}} {'format'}
```

Some examples for using the `format` are:

```
plot 'file' using 1:($2+$3) '%lf,%lf,%lf'
```

or

```
plot 'MyData' using "%*lf%lf%*20[^\n]%lf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it because I omitted the comma after the first plot statement below:

plot "hourly.tab" using 1:2, \
    "hourly.tab" using 1:3

I guess it was interpreting my \ as garbage (or the 2nd plot command).